# In Azure Search, can an indexer combine information from different documents to a single index item without them overwritting each other?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

My goal is to create a single searchable Azure Index that has all of the relevant information currently stored in many different sql tables.

I'm also using an Azure Cognitive Service to add additional info from related documents. Each document is tied to only a single item in my Index, but each item in the index will be tied to many documents.

According to my understanding, if two documents have the same value for the indexer's Key, then the index will overwrite the extracted information from the first document with the information extracted from the second. I'm hoping there's a way to *append* the information instead of overwriting it. For example: if two documents relate to the same index item, I want the values mapped to keyphrases for that item to include the keyphrases found in the first document and the keyphrases found in the second document.

Is this possible? Is there a different way I should be approaching this?
If it is possible, can I do it without having duplicate values?

Currently I have multiple indexes and I'm combining the search results from each one, but this seems inefficient and likely messes up the default scoring algorithm.

Every code example I find only has one document for each index item and doesn't address my problem. Admittedly, I haven't tried to set up my index as described above, because it would take a lot of refactoring, and I'm confident it would just overwrite itself.

I am currently creating my indexes and indexers programmatically using dotnet. I'm assuming my code isn't relevant to my question, but I can provide it if need be.

Thank you so much! I'd appreciate any feedback you can give.

Edit: I'm thinking about creating a custom skill to do the aggregation for me, but I don't know how the skill would access access everything it needs. It needs the extracted info from the current document, and it needs the previously aggregated info from previous documents. I guess the custom skill could perform a search on the index and get the item that way, but that sounds dangerously hacky. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-data-import):

Indexing actions: upload, merge, mergeOrUpload, delete

You can control the type of indexing action on a per-document basis, specifying whether the document should be uploaded in full, merged with existing document content, or deleted.

Whether you use the REST API or an SDK, the following document operations are supported for data import:

Upload, similar to an "upsert" where the document is inserted if it is new, and updated or replaced if it exists. If the document is missing values that the index requires, the document field's value is set to null.

merge updates a document that already exists, and fails a document that cannot be found. Merge replaces existing values. For this reason, be sure to check for collection fields that contain multiple values, such as fields of type Collection(Edm.String). For example, if a tags field starts with a value of ["budget"] and you execute a merge with ["economy", "pool"], the final value of the tags field is ["economy", "pool"]. It won't be ["budget", "economy", "pool"].

mergeOrUpload behaves like merge if the document exists, and upload if the document is new.

delete removes the entire document from the index. If you want to remove an individual field, use merge instead, setting the field in question to null.

Comment: This is very helpful. In all my digging I forgot that I can also push documents into my index. Am I correct however that these indexing actions are only available via pushing? In other words, I can't specify that an indexer uses mergeOrUpload. I have a lot of data already that I'd like to simply run an indexer on, though I suppose I can come up with a push solution. It also looks like I can't attach a skillset when pushing data to an index. If I'm wrong please let me know as this would make implementation much easier.